# Connect to RemoteApp Linux Mint 18.3

Tags: linux-mint, remote, remote-desktop

At our company we run a Remote Desktop Gateway with RemoteApps 
Does anyone have a good and easy way to connect and use these from within Linux Mint 18.3?

Been trying different things and a work around is an openVPN server and just connect directly to the Domain Controller and Remote Desktop Server.

It would how ever be very neat to be able to just launch the RemoteApp instead.

Answer (score 0):

For connecting to just Remote Desktop I've got a good experience with [remmina](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/remmina-plugin-rdp) & [remmina-plugin-rdp](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/remmina-plugin-rdp), concerning RemoteApps there's some discussion on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148159/remmina-remoteapp-over-rdp) (not enough reputation to just comment yet).